# Running iOS Application on Simulator without Building App

Tags: ios, xcode

I was wondering if it was possible to 'Run' an Xcode Project on the simulator without having it 'Build the Source' first.

When I click the 'Run' button in Xcode 4.0.2, it builds first, then runs it.

Is it possible to run without building? 
If it's possible, how do you do it?

**Edit:** This may sound like a strange question, but I have acquired an Xcode project from a third party who is telling me to Run the code without Building it to get it running on the simulator. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but.

Go to Product -> Perform Action -> Run Without Building

Comment: Also, you can hold Control and press the Run button.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this used to work.  In recent Xcode versions, Command-Control-R reinstalls the app, which breaks the ability to debug background downloads.  Ick.

Answer (score 17):

You have three options:

- `ctrl-cmd-r`
- hold `ctrl` and click the run (*play icon*) button
- Within menu goto `Product` > `Perform Action` > `Run Without Building`

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 10 right now is ^+Cmd+R

Answer (score -4):

AFAIK, this is how every IDE works.  You can't run the program until it is at least built once, whether implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: The issue is that Xcode 4 normally builds the code *every time* you run. This is often what you want -- you don't want to have to remember to build before running every time you make a change. But sometimes you'd like to run the program a few times without changing the code and without building each time.

Answer (score -4):

Objective C is a compiled language. The Code cant be interpreted

Comment: Right, I know this very well. Hence, the edit I posted in my post. I don't want to contact this third-party until I'm 100% sure this isn't doable, even though I know it shouldn't be possible, for the reason you mentioned.