# Xcode 11 re-installs app to device before every run

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Every time the project is run ("Build and Run")—even if there are no changes to the code—Xcode is reinstalling to the device. The project is not being recompiled from scratch, so this is not a duplicate of [XCode compiles entire project each time I run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596671/xcode-compiles-entire-project-each-time-i-run); it just (re)installs every time.

There's a fair but of supporting content (audio files, etc.), so this is making progress/debugging extremely slow. My colleague is working on the same code base, but doesn't have this issue.

Comment: I think it is intended to do that. I'm not sure how your colleague manages to run an app without installing it first.

Comment: Not first run, every time I run. I've been working in Xcode for many, many years and it's never done this before.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The question is perfectly unambiguous and concerns an unusual behaviour that is impeding development significantly... ridiculous... Certainly if a solution is found, it will be a great benefit to anyone who has the misfortune of encountering this in future...

Comment: Did you clean out Derived Data and so on?

Comment: I have, but I’ll try the full gamut of deleting derived data and restarting both the phone and my laptop. Thanks. I have noticed that my phone keeps popping up the “trust this computer” alert, lately. Which also doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Having this same issue now, did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry @AbdullahAjmal, I'm sure I got past it, but it's been ages and I don't recall how it was resolved... I'm not doing any iOS dev at the moment either, ... apologies

Comment: @jbm hey, no worries at all. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run and attach only without building the app by pressing Ctrl-Command-R key. More ways to do that is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38847503/6426085)

Comment: Right, good thought. Not a solution, but an improvement. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped :) @mrwheet